# Get the insert and update SQL queries from LINQ To Sql data context

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ To Sql data context, with a mapping to tables User and Group. A user belongs to a Group.

So I would like to get the corresponding SQL generated for Insert/Update by data context against a particular entity.

For e.g.

```
  using (var context = new TestBedDataContext())
        {
            using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
            {
                context.Users.InsertOnSubmit(new User
                    {
                        Name = "Test",
                        Password = "Password",
                        Username = "test",
                        Group1 = new Group
                        {
                            Name = "Group1"
                        }
                    });

                // Get the query for User entity
            }
        }
```

Here I would like to get the queries that will be generated for inserting a new user along with Group entity.

I know `context.Log` property can be used to capture the entire SQL generated, the problem with that approach is, it will catch all the SQL which are not in my interests (like change scripts for some other entities)

Comment: You could capture the INSERT and UPDATES at the database level via the SQL Profiler.  You could filter on the User tables OBJECT_ID so you only see events performed for that entity.

Comment: @DarrenDavies yeah that will work but my requirement is different. I would like to capture SQL from C# code and I don't want LINQ To SQL to make that changes directly to the database (that is why I didn't committed the transaction... please see the posted code), it will done in later stages by executing the captured scripts.

Comment: There is no need to capture the scripts. You can just call context.SubmitChanges later on. You really do not want to use Linq-to-sql if you want to execute the scripts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void addPatientInformation() {
    using(DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext()) {
        myDb.PatientInfos.InsertOnSubmit(new PatientInfo {
            Phy_ID = physcianID,
            Pat_First_Name = txtFirstName.Text,
            Pat_Middle_Init = txtMiddleName.Text,
            Pat_Last_Name = txtLastName.Text,
            Pat_Gender = cmbGender.Text,
            Pat_Marital_Status = cmbMaritalStatus.Text,
            Pat_Date_Of_Birth = dtpDOB.Value,
            Pat_Home_Add = txtHomeAdd.Text,
            Pat_Home_Num = txtPhone.Text,
            Pat_Work_Add = txtWorkAdd.Text,
            Pat_Work_Num = txtWorkPhone.Text,
            Pat_Prim_Physician = txtPrimPhysician.Text,
            Pat_Ref_Physician = txtRefePhysician.Text,
        });
        myDb.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```